# Pulling nested GraphQL queries into react-table

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-table

I need to know why GraphQL nested queries aren't working specifically while using react-table. I'm trying to render a table, and one of my columns, `Item Count`, isn't displaying specifically because the query is nested.

GET_SHIPMENTS query:

```
export const GET_SHIPMENTS = gql`
      {
        shipments {
          created_at
          id
          status
          orders {
            order_items
          }
        }
      }
    `;
```

I've gone onto the spectrum chat located here -> https://spectrum.chat/react-table?tab=posts and have had no luck with what they have offered. The original solution was to map over an array and define entry points for the schema to display properly.

Example:

```
data={data.shipments.map((entry, index) => {
    {
        id: entry.id,
        status: entry.status,
        order_items: entry.orders.order_items
    }
)}
```

This gave me an unexpected token error, which I cannot resolve.

My React Table is being rendered with a HOC to display data from my shipments query.

```
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import { GET_SHIPMENTS } from '../graphql/ShipmentQueries';
import ReactTable from 'react-table';
import {
  Card,
  CardBody,
  Row,
} from "reactstrap";

function OrderTable ({ loading, shipments }) {
  const columns = [
    {
      Header: 'ID',
      accessor: 'id',
    },
    {
      Header: 'Status',
      accessor: 'status',
    },
    {
      Header: 'Item Count',
      accessor: 'order_items',
    },
    {
      Header: 'Time Stamp',
      accessor: 'created_at',
    },
  ];

if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
    return (
        <div className="content">
          <Row className="mt-5">
              <Card>
                <CardBody>
                  <ReactTable
                    data={shipments}
                    columns={columns}
                    sortable={true}
                    resizable={false}
                    minRows={10}
                  />
                </CardBody>
              </Card>
          </Row>
        </div>
    );
  }

  export const OrderTableWithData = graphql(GET_SHIPMENTS, {
    props: ({data: { loading, shipments }}) => ({
      loading,
      shipments,
    }),
  })(OrderTable);
```

The data from `order_item` is not displaying, so I'm wondering how to resolve this issue so this information can be displayed in my table. I cannot edit the schema.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up that orders is an array and I should have written my accessor as such:

`orders[0].order_items` .. so it wasn't necessarily React Table. It was the type of data that I had to iterate over.

Comment: You can also use functions like:




for some reason, dot notation doesn't work for me, so I just use functions like:

accessor: ({order_items}) => order_items.map(() => return) or nested object

or

accessor: ({order_item}) => order_item.id

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can access nested data using dot notation for your accessor.  Have you tried `accessor: 'orders.order_items'`?

Comment: Unfortunately that is something I've already tried, and it is still not working. I've also tried using different formatting such as this:

`orders[order_items]` just in case it was taken as an array, but it's still not displaying.

Comment: Can you post the exact data structure you're feeding to the table?

Comment: It's in the `GET_SHIPMENTS` query that I posted above. I can't edit that structure of that schema in order to grab the order_count from orders.

Comment: But the other columns are displaying correctly? What is the error you're receiving, and could you log/post the data just to be sure? I can't think of why else a simple nested accessor wouldn't work.

Comment: The other columns are displaying correctly. The data is here -> https://imgur.com/0YB5pYx but doesn't display the order_count under the orders object. This is for when I have the accessor as `orders.order_items`. I get the same result if I just put in `order_items`. I do not get any errors, I just don't get the `order_items` displayed at all.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't view Imgur links here. So you're saying order_items is NOT under the orders object? Can you post this as text or upload to another site?

Comment: Correct, `order_items` is not under the orders object when I make the accessor display as follow `orders.order_items`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm kinda confused.  I can't help without seeing the data structure you're feeding into the table.

Comment: So I ended up figuring it out. I wasn't iterating over an array. It should have been accessed like this `orders[0].order_items` ... since orders is an array. sorry about the confusion, thanks for trying to help me, and I apologize if this was a time suck!